# Osascript Music get current track shareable url

Tags: osascript

Is there a way to get the shareable URL for the current track playing via osascript?

For instance: https://music.apple.com/br/album/never-gonna-give-you-up/1558533900?i=1558534271&l=en-GB

Thanks in advance

I tried get the properties

```
tell application "Music"
    tell current track
        get properties
    end tell
end tell
```

But the URL isn't there

```json
{class:URL track, id:4037, index:1, name:"Never Gonna Give You Up", persistent ID:"F6833B93D22A6372", database ID:4033, date added:date "Monday, 21 August 2023 12:57:39", time:"3:33", duration:213.572998046875, artist:"Rick Astley", album artist:"", composer:"", album:"Whenever You Need Somebody", genre:"Pop", track count:0, track number:1, disc count:0, disc number:1, volume adjustment:0, year:1987, comment:"", EQ:"", kind:"", media kind:song, enabled:true, start:0.0, finish:213.572998046875, played count:0, skipped count:0, compilation:false, rating:0, bpm:0, grouping:"", bookmarkable:false, bookmark:0.0, shufflable:true, lyrics:"", category:"", description:"", episode number:0, unplayed:true, sort name:"", sort album:"", sort artist:"", sort composer:"", sort album artist:"", release date:date "Monday, 27 July 1987 09:00:00", loved:false, disliked:false, album loved:false, album disliked:false, work:"", movement:"", movement number:0, movement count:0}
```

What i want:
https://music.apple.com/br/album/never-gonna-give-you-up/1558533900?i=1558534271&l=en-GB